# gunicorn with compiled python source

Tags: python, pyinstaller, gunicorn

I have compiled my python files including gunicorn with PyInstaller on centOS 7. I'm trying to run those executables on another centOS 7 machine I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manage'` but my module `manage` is present in the same directory in executable form. Here is the full command and its output.

`./gunicorn -c /opt/myproject/configuration/gunicorn_conf.ini --bind unix:/etc/myproject/myproject.sock -m 007 manage:app --preload`

```
!!!
!!! WARNING: configuration file should have a valid Python extension.
!!!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
  File "site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
  File "site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
  File "site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
  File "site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 58, in __init__
  File "site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 118, in setup
  File "site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
  File "site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
  File "site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
  File "site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
  File "importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manage'
[20316] Failed to execute script gunicorn
```

Am I missing something here? or gunicorn does not work with compiled files? if it does not, then is there any alternative for it other than using the source?

Comment: Are you trying to start the binary file with GUnicorn? If so this isn't going to work as the binary isn't a WSGI compliant application. Can you not just invoke the binary such as `./<binary package>`? Happy to help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue similar where the import failed for `gunicorn.glogger`. I solved it by adding the import to the top of the module explicitly.

`from gunicorn import glogger`

I am using gunicorn 20.0.4 and I do not see a module called `manage`. Is it possible this is a dependency from another library?

#### Another possible Fix

Hidden imports are specified in the [pyinstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html?highlight=--hidden-import#listing-hidden-imports), you can use the switch `--hidden-import` in your build command to include implicitly used libraries within the binary. If you have multiple imports you can use a `:` to separate the list.

#### Invoking GUnicorn

Green unicorn is built to be started from the command line. This is easy to do within a docker container or by running the command on a host machine. Unfortunately this is not the case when using pyinstaller as you need a "python" entry point. I had to build a custom application from the [gunicorn docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/custom.html) (copy/paste) to allow my application to start up as a script. From here I was able to tell pyinstaller to use this script to start the server under `if __name__ == '__main__':`

See example below.

#### Bugs

Even with the binary built with required dependencies I ran into an issue where the web application would stop responding after a random number of requests. I did not investigate further as it pushed me into another direction of building an RPM for easy installation.

#### Update February 4th, 2021

Setting arguments to GUnicorn.

```py
import gunicorn.app.base


class StandaloneApplication(gunicorn.app.base.BaseApplication):

    def __init__(self, app, options=None):
        self.options = options or {}
        self.application = app
        super().__init__()

    def load_config(self):
        config = {key: value for key, value in self.options.items()
                  if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None}
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

    def load(self):
        return self.application


if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = {
        'bind': 'unix:/etc/myproject/myproject.sock',
        'preload': True,
        'config': '/opt/myproject/configuration/gunicorn_conf.ini',
        'umask': '007',
        '<argument name>': '<argument value>',
    }
    StandaloneApplication(<your flask application object or factory>, options).run()
```

Haven't tested this specific setup but I am using something very similar. Each of the GUnicorn switch/option in the CLI maps directly to python variables, you can find that [here](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html). These options are set in our `options` dictionary which the server will accept as the second augument in the `StandaloneApplication` constructor. You will need to pass in the `app` object as the first argument or application factory function from your `manage` module.

I do recommend looking at [python configuration files](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/configure.html?highlight=ini#configuration-file). You can also export these as environment variables and use `os.getenv("<env name>")` to access them. It just keeps the server from using hardcoded values that other users will have to change in the source.

Comment: manage is where I have my entry point. I compiled my manage too but gunicorn command is expecting entry point to be of source code, not the compiled one. That's the real problem.

Comment: yeah so when you execute the binary it should be done just by calling `./<binary name>`. since gunicorn is already packaged into the project you don't need to use the gunicorn CLI. That being said in your `manage` module you will likely need to build a custom gunicorn server object as stated/linked above. That new object will inherit from `gunicorn.app.base.BaseApplication`. Then, you can invoke gunicorn in your python `manage` module using `run()`

Comment: ok so now if I compile manage with proper dependencies, I don't need gunicorn cli, I have to directly run the manage, right? if yes, then what about my gunicorn args (see question)

Comment: See update, this should get you in the right direction. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Errors like `Import module errors` and `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named` occurs when PyInstaller can't detect some python modules.

Those are known as Hidden Imports.

**=> See answer from Stephen Collins above on how to fix this.**

Here are some troubleshooting information:

- You can also use  `pyinstaller --debug=imports` to list hidden imports
  ([doc](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports))
- avoid unexpected runtime error by reviewing the file  created by pyInstaller that list delayed and conditional dependencies:

```
$ cat warn-app.txt
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running your program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional modules. For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

Types if import:
* top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
* conditional: imported within an if-statement
* delayed: imported within a function
* optional: imported within a try-except-statement

IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
            tracking down the missing module yourself. Thanks!

missing module named org - imported by copy (optional)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by pickle (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named winreg - imported by importlib._bootstrap_external (conditional), mimetypes (optional), urllib.request (delayed, conditional, optional), platform (delayed, optional), werkzeug.debug (delayed, conditional)
missing module named nt - imported by os (delayed, conditional, optional), ntpath (optional), shutil (conditional), importlib._bootstrap_external (conditional), pathlib (conditional), ctypes (delayed, conditional)
```